# Auto sizing CCLabelBMFont

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

was wondering if anyone has any experience in resizing a `CCLabelBMFont` to fit in a given box. Currently, it's being done iteratively (a `while` loop) and is pretty darn expensive. It initially makes the scale to 1 and the width to the box, then it shrinks down the scale while maintaining the same width (essentially like decreasing the font size) until it sees it no longer bleeds outside the box.

It doesn't seem as simple as just scaling it, because of word wrap, wondering if y'all had any solution to this that doesn't involve scaling it, checking it, scaling it, checking it...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the width of the box and the width of the label at scale 1.0. So if you take the difference between box width and label width and then divide that by the box width, you get the scale factor you need to fit the label in the box (width-wise).

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the best, thanks so much worked great, I was wayyy overcomplicating it ^_^